# How to set android view's layout_alignParentEnd property by code?

Tags: java, android

How can I set the `alignParentEnd` property programmatically?

I searched all over the Android Developer website, but I couldn't find any reference to setting properties like `alignParentEnd` in code. It is only explained how to set them in XML. Where could I find documentation for something like this in the future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LayoutParams` are used to set layout properties in code. `alignParentEnd` is a property of `RelativeLayout` so you have to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. You can find the documentation [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

---

So to set the property in code you can use the `addRule()` method of the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. For example you can do this:

```
// Create the LayoutParams
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// Add all the rules you need
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
...

// Once you are done set the LayoutParams to the layout
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can find a list of all rules which you can set with `addRule()` [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#constants).

Comment: `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);`       Field requires API level 17 `android.widget.RelativeLayout#ALIGN_PARENT_END`

Answer (score 5):

Parameter are added in View and ViewGroup using LayoutParam.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) my_child_view.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
my_child_view.setLayoutParams(params);
```